# Want to fetch some data from an excel sheet to another using VLookup and macro

Tags: excel, vba

workbook 1           workbook 2

ID  Value
1     a
2     b

ID   Value
1
2

so i want to fetch the b value from workbook 1 using the value 2 and put that in workbook 2 along side 2.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Below is the formula. It will only work if both the workbook are opened in same instance.

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,[Book1]Sheet1!A$1:B$3,2,0)
```

[image]

If multiple instance of excel is running then task manager would show more than one image name as EXCEL.EXE in task manager processes window.

[image]

Comment: +1.  I think this also works even if one workbook is not open, as long as you specify the full path of the workbook.  Entering the formulas as you have, the full path will automatically insert when you close the file(s). This of course requires that the workbook be saved, so that it has a full path property.

Comment: Thanks santosh, but  i gave a small example for better understanding. but i want to do it in a loop and for large number of data

Comment: @ArkaBanerjee **Always avoid loops**. To know why refer this [**link**](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/free-training/ExcelVBA1/excelvba1lesson11.htm). It can be easily achieved using the formula as shown in the above code. Did that help?